# an error occurred while processing this directive

Tags: php, directive

On my site:

http://bammeh.com/tempemail/

I keep getting erros all over my site when using PHP files that arent CHMOD to 644 or 755.

If I chmod recursively this directory 755 I get:

> [an error occurred while processing this directive]

And I f I chmod it recursively to 644 I get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /disposable/admin/ on this server.

Help? :( I use Hostmonster as my host. is it on their end?

Comment: I have read other peoples posts and I have tried their answers, with no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try claiming ownership of the files first with `chown` - be careful with this though because if you set the permissions tightly and not loosely, you might have trouble accessing them any other way than through PHP itself.

Comment: Thanks! Got it figured out :)

Comment: i have also same issue please give me proper solutions. below my website URL you can see error : 
https://www.testingforms.com/oc_3020

Answer (score 14):

I come a cross with similar sort of issue, following solution work for me.

Check your code: you might have wrote a comment
<!--#some comment-->" add space "<!--[add space ] #some comment [add space] -->" Like this "<!-- #some comment -->

Comment: This simply breaks SSI directives.

Comment: I don't know how you realized this was the fix- but bless your heart. ty!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by just adding the .htaccess file in the root directory with the default code and it started working. Also, after adding I need to update the permalink in the WP admin setting.

```
`   # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress`
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: i have also same issue please give me proper solutions. below my website URL you can see error : testingforms.com/oc_3020

Answer (score 2):

It's all about file permission issue, Now it's working for me...

Folder permission must be 744 other permissions like (752, 753, 756, and 777) cause limitation and will not work..

File permission must be 644 other permissions like (642, 643, 646 and 647) cause limitation and will not work..

Comment: Permissions should almost never be 777 on anything, but how could that possibly 'cause limitation' on anything?

Comment: i have also same issue please give me proper solutions. below my website URL you can see error : testingforms.com/oc_3020

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. It happened when copied files from linux system to another server. I believe file permissions and group got messaged up.

I solved it by moving the files to windows PC where these permissions things are cleared and then unzip it on Linux server. Although its not the correct way but i find it simple enough to try once.

Answer (score 1):

As jktech11 says, its all about a permission issue. for me permission 755 for folders and permission 644 for files worked. FYI You can change the permission via file zilla or command prompt if its in local host.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions here and non worked for me.

Actually the shell help file was the one that properly helped me correct permissions and I advise anyone to do this.

When I typed:

```
ls -la public_html
```

I showed I had made a wrong user attribution to a folder cousin this same error message.

I tried all the solutions here and from many other threads but none worked. So I typed:

```
chown --help
```

and it showed me that I needed to use -hR 
Examples:

```
Examples:

 chown root /u        Change the owner of /u to "root".
  chown root:staff /u  Likewise, but also change its group to "staff".
  chown -hR root /u    Change the owner of /u and subfiles to "root".
```

In my case:

```
chown -hR usernameiwanttoownthefile /home/rootpath/public_html/sitefolder
```

Fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

SuPHP was the root cause of me getting this error. I switched to a new VPS and by default it was using SuPHP. I switched to use PHP-FPM which allowed the scripts with permissions 664 to execute properly.

The current CRM I'm using had issues during the updates and they were failing because the file permissions set to 664 for some files which were part of the update. I couldn't change the permissions of these during the update process. It needed to be able to execute all the files otherwise the updates would fail.

After the updates I run a script to reset the folders to 755 and files to 644.

Hope this helps anyone who runs into this again.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem with justhost.com cpanel when creating the file from Aptana 3 using remote ftp connection.
I solved it by creating the file using the Cpanel File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check your html code for html commenting like `<!--{space}comment-->` if there is, then remove the space and upload the html file. Hope it helps!